# "failed to start io pipe copy" when running docker exec

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have a simple MySQL data dump script that exports all data from a MySQL Docker volume. It goes like this:

```sh
dbPassword="password"
sourceDb="production"
localFile="$sourceDb.sql.gz"

dbContainer=$(docker-compose ps -q db)
docker exec "$dbContainer" /usr/bin/mysqldump -u root --password="$dbPassword" "$sourceDb" \
    | gzip > db/"$localFile"
```

This used to work just fine. However, starting some time ago — perhaps related to a `containerd` or `docker` update? — it stopped working. It now errors out with this:

> failed to start io pipe copy: containerd-shim: opening ...-stdout failed: open ...-stdout: no such file or directory: unknown

The `…` is a hash like 162e7281bd2fa30….

I'm running Docker version 19.03.6, build 369ce74a3c under Ubuntu 18.04.

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I presume that an Ubuntu `containerd` (unattended) upgrade somehow corrupted the state of Docker, internally.

Stopping the database container and restarting it made it work again.